# What is the highest range mosquito can be detected via Microphone?

Tags: mosquitoes, bioacoustics

Just wondering when a mosquito attack at night I can hear it around my head, shoulders upper corps. Is it any statistic how far our ears or a microphone could detect it is nearby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In accordance with the article [Using mobile phones as acoustic sensors for high-throughput mosquito surveillance](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5663474/) mobile phone microphones can detect moscitos in 10 to 100 mm range (depends on a model). In an empty room mosquito can be detected at approx. 3 m ([Sound Pressure Level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_pressure_level)).